# Ansible global inventory variables

Tags: ansible

I have a variable that is different for every inventory which i need to access from the playbook. i have tried:

```
[globalvars]
db=dbhost

[atlanta]
host1
host2

[boston]
host3
```

I want to use the "db" variable somehow in my playbooks, i have tried various combinations but i have not been able to access the "db" variable from within the playbook.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To define a "global" variable you will need to define it as a variable for the `all` group

```
[all:vars]
db=dbhost

[atlanta]
host1
host2

[boston]
host3
```

This is considered not to be a best practice.
In ansible you can define `group_vars` in a separate directory/file like the following:

```
# file: group_vars/all
db: "dbhost"

# file: inventory/hosts
[atlanta]
host1
host2

[boston]
host3
```

`group_vars` is a directory in your top dir ( where your playbook is ), ansible will include the var files of the group(s) in the play.

Anyway, in both cases you will be able to access the variable as `{{ db }}` in your templates/playbooks

Comment: But if i put it in "group_vars" then it won't be inventory-specific

Comment: Yes sorry, you're right, they won't be inventory specific. Then the first solution should be ok for your case